# Failed to resolve: com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.1

Tags: android

Export the unity project and imported into native app. I want to show `lottie` animation before launching the unity player.

gradle dependency `com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.1`, it throws `Error.(Failed to resolve: com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.1)`.

For same dependency added in new project without unity, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'
}
```

Try to add this to your gradle files this is the last lottie versoin,take a look [here](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)

Comment: can you add some of your gradle file,and where you use it?

Comment: try with the new 2.5.5

Comment: everything okay? did it help you?